# How to ignore vscode events from firing within a certain time interval?

Tags: api, visual-studio-code, event-handling, vscode-extensions

For example, if I trigger `onDidChangeTextDocument` events consecutively, with an interval of at maximum 1 second, then I would like to avoid this event's associated logic.
However, if 1 second has passed since the lastest `onDidChangeTextDocument` has been triggered, I would like for it to proceed with its logic.

Comment: start a timer to call the actual callback, and reset the timer every `onDidChangeTextDocument`, or use the `DocumentLinkProvider` it has this functionality already, just return an empty array

Answer (score 2):

This approach is known as "coalescing events". A typical approach is to [start a timer when an event appears](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/ExtensionHost.ts#L296) with the required interval. Every new event restarts the timer, so it never triggers unless there are no new events within the timer value. The triggered timer then calls any further code, handling the coalesced events. This might cause some problems if you have to process all data sent by each event. In that case you have to collect that data on each invocation of your event handler.

Here's code to handle changes per file in a VS Code extension:

```js
        private changeTimers = new Map<string, ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>(); // Keyed by file name.

        workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument((event: TextDocumentChangeEvent) => {
            if (event.contentChanges.length > 0) {
                const fileName = event.document.fileName;

                const timer = this.changeTimers.get(fileName);
                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                }

                this.changeTimers.set(fileName, setTimeout(() => {
                    this.changeTimers.delete(fileName);
                    ... your processing here
                }, 1000));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Greetings Mike, thank for your answer! I didn't get to fully test your implementation for my example. but I found a more concise and practical solution by using [ts-debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-debounce)